# run time error 4198 with Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error, copy-paste

This code worked for a while but now I get the 4198 run time error when running it.
What I need is to find and copy all text in a given style (named Questions) and paste at the end of document.

```
Sub CopyAIRs()

' CopyAIRs Macro

    Dim styl As Style
    Set styl = ActiveDocument.Styles("Questions")
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Style = styl
        .Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
    End With
    
    Do While rng.Find.Execute
        rng.Select
        With Selection
            .Copy
            .EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
            .MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
            .EndKey Unit:=wdLine
            .TypeParagraph
            .PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)            
        End With
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

I checked the clipboard and it appears to work in the first "round" of the loop, but it gives this error. In the latest try I had 6 numbered paragraphs in this specific style. **Note:**In developer mode it works when going through the steps with F8, but error comes up with F5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As you want to collect all text w/o formatting (wdFormatPlainText), `Copy/Paste` is not necessary.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.InsertBefore method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertbefore?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm157155430)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.InsertParagraphAfter method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertparagraphafter?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm157155489)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CopyAIRs()
    Dim styl As Style, docRng As Range, endRng As Range
    Set styl = ActiveDocument.Styles("Strong")
    Set docRng = ActiveDocument.Range
    With docRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Style = styl
        .Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
    End With
    Do While docRng.Find.Execute
        With ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range
            If .Characters.Count > 1 Then
                .InsertParagraphAfter
            End If
        End With
        ActiveDocument.Range.Characters.Last.InsertBefore docRng.Text
    Loop
End Sub
```

---

Update:

> Question: I need to past the found contents just above a "marker" in the last line. Therefore the text need to be pasted in the "second last " line for example

```vb
    Do While docRng.Find.Execute
        With ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range
            .InsertParagraphBefore
            .InsertBefore docRng.Text
        End With
    Loop
```

[image]

Comment: I've revised the code. You don't have to use `Selection`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more question. In my original code I used ".MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1" because I need to paste the found contents just above a "marker" in the last line. 

Therefore the text need to be pasted in the "second last " line for example. How can I resolve this with your suggested code?

Comment: @GabrielLobo Your new comment is same as before (which is gone). Have you tried the updated code?

Comment: Thanks Taller. The new code is not working (I was precipitated in saying "yes" before). 

The last line in the document says " DO NOT DELETE – Ensure questions are above this line" . After a few tests it keeps pasting below.

Comment: I've tested the code before posting it. See the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: I will try to figure out what is going on.  Thanks a lot.
Funny fact is that the original code I posted in the question does not work in my job computer but does work in my personal computer.